# Troubleshooting 74LS136D in Multisim

Tags: digital-logic, simulation, logic-gates, multisim

[image]

Hello. I couldn't seem to get my U1A to work. I understand the open collector logic gates, like 74LS136, require a pull-up resister in its output terminal. An open collector needs to be powered-on. I think it's true from the way the output does not have any ammeter reading unless you provided it with a 5-V DC voltage.

Now, my problem is that the logic gate isn't enabled to the extent that the reading still stays at 0.05A despite its two inputs being 0 (in which I know that isn't the case for a XOR logic).

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

- Use a voltmeter not a current meter on the output.

[image]

- Use 10 kohm pull-down resistors on your chip inputs.
- Don't use LEDs without series current limiting resistors.
- R1 should be more like 1 kohm.